# Xamarin and cross-platform webservice access + json parsing

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm searching for a way to retrieve data (formatted in json) from an API and parse them.

I really want to use the code both for android and for IOS. I already saw examples but they didn't work for both platforms.

If you can provide me examples for connection, retrieving and for json, it is the best for me because I didn't find great docs about cross-platform (quite simple) implementation.

Comments Welcome !

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used Newtonsoft's json library in a monotouch solution

Find the source code [here](https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json).

As far as retrieving the data - that depends on your API, I suspect it's a web API with HTTP calls? If that's the case you can further elaborate on this, obviously exception handling and threading is up to you:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create (url);
...
 request.BeginGetResponse ((r) =>
 {
     string res = null;
     using (StreamReader srd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
         res = srd.ReadToEnd ();
     }
     T jres = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> (res);
 }, null);
```

Comment: Okay Thanks @Sten Petrov , I will try it but I have a "No overload for method 'BeginGetResponse' takes 1 arguments".

Comment: @clement check update, added `, null);` in the end, that should do

Comment: +1 for Newtonsoft. I've also used it in lots of PCL libraries too - shared across MonoDroid and MonoTouch

Comment: @StenPetrov : okay thanks. It still Two errors on the line of the deserialization : "The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly"  and "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found". Do you have an idea about how revolve them?

Comment: The code above is a sample, not to be compiled directly. `T` is a generic type, either wrap that code in a generic method or replace `T` with your specific type if you don't know about generics (learn them, saves lots of code). `Systeh.Object` - try putting "using System;" on top of your class

Comment: Instead of using HttpWebRequest you can also make use webclient class for API request,simpler and better way i think. also webclient is a higher level abstraction built on top of HttpWebRequest. check here http://appliedcodelog.blogspot.in/2015/06/requesting-rest-webservice-with-json-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using nuget to download Newtonsoft, you need to download it from here:http://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net/

Comment: yes but it was not available atht aht time :-) Thanks for the update

Comment: It's just fine to use the nuget package